# SQL Server 2008 Merge Soft Delete Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, merge

I'm trying to perform a soft delete on a row in my target table using the SQL server 2008 MERGE command.

I think this should fall under the "when not matched by source" section, since the source is missing the row and the target still has it.  All I want to do is set the IsActive bit to false, but I'm getting an error.

> "Attempting to set a non-NULL-able column's value to NULL."

What am I missing?

The Users table is:

```
[ID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[LastName] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[EmailAddress] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL
```

The Merge statement is:

```
merge into Users
using TempUserTable lu
on Users.ID = TempUserTable.ID
when matched then
update set
    ID = lu.ID,
    FirstName = lu.FirstName,
    LastName = lu.LastName,
    EMailAddress = lu.EmailAddress,
    IsActive = lu.Status

when not matched then
    insert (ID, FirstName, LastName, EmailAddress, IsActive)
    values (lu.ID, lu.FirstName, lu.LastName, lu.EmailAddress, lu.Status)
when not matched by source then
    update set  IsActive = 0;
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Converting the query into two separate insert or update statements resolved the problem.. Or should I say, side-stepped it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* get this to work exactly as you want but for me I needed to add a condition in the NOT MATCHED line.

So try something like...

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
                    AND TARGET.[IsActive] = 1 
                    AND TARGET.[DeletedOn] IS NULL 
    THEN UPDATE
    SET 
      TARGET.[IsActive] = 0, 
      TARGET.[DeletedOn] = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your temp table `TempUserTable` either has a `NULL` in the `IsActive` column or the `ID` column.